# Sending cell info from one view controller to another Swift and Parse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, swift2

I have a tableView displaying all the users on ViewController1(VC1) when the currentUser chooses a cell it segues to ViewController2(VC2) and needs to display all the user information from the cell that was clicked onto labels and a PFImageView. I have all the user info for the last cell displaying. So even though I clicked a different cell the next VC is only displaying the user at the end of the list. So lets say my user cell list display starts with Aisling, roger, dave and john. I click on cell 'Aisling' and segue to VC2, it displays all of Johns profile info.

VC1:
under the class:

```
var appUsers = [PFUser]()
var userToShow = PFUser()
```

then:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let singleCell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mySingleCellid") as! CustomCell

    let userObject = appUsers[indexPath.row] as PFObject

    singleCell.userName.text = userObject["name"] as? String
    singleCell.userAge.text = userObject["age"] as? String
    singleCell.usersProfileImage.file = userObject["image"] as? PFFile
    singleCell.usersProfileImage.loadInBackground()
    // when userToShow is here it shows the user detail of the last cell everytime
userToShow = appUsers[indexPath.row]

    return singleCell

} // cell for row

// when userToShow is here it crashes the app when the cell is clicked giving the error:unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       userToShow = appUsers[indexPath.row]

      func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "userProfileDetailsSegue" {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? UserProfileDetailsViewController {
                destinationVC.userToShowDetail = userToShow
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On VC2: 
below the class:

```
  var userToShowDetail = PFUser()
```

Then:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    userName.text = userToShowDetail["name"] as? String
    userBio.text = userToShowDetail["bio"] as? String
    userAge.text = userToShowDetail["age"] as? String
    userProfile.file = userToShowDetail["image"] as? PFFile
    userProfile.loadInBackground()
}
```

**It only displays in VC2 the user details belonging to the user in the last cell on VC1. Instead of the user details belonging to the user in the cell that was chosen.**

Stuck on this for a few weeks now and my deadline is pushing on can't solve it any help would really be appreciated!!!  All links and help I could find online is for C# and obj c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Segue Layout]

VC1

```
//PUT THIS IN THE FIRST VC CLASS
var appUserResult: PFUser?

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //TAKE OUT LET - YOU'VE ALREADY DEFINED AS CLASS VAR
    appUserResult = appUsers[indexPath.row]

    print(appUserResult)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openVC2", sender: self)
}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if segue.identifier == "openVC2" {
    let indexPath = self.resultsPageTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

//INDEXPATH ISN'T AVAILABLE IN PREPAREFORSEGUE
//let userToShow = appUsers[indexPath.row]

let newVc = segue.destinationViewController as! UserProfileDetailsViewController
  //USE THE CLASS VARIABLE TO PASS
  newVc.userToShowDetail = appUserResult
```

VC2

```
var userToShowDetail: PFUser?
```

In storyboard, delete the old segue. Create a new one from VC1 to VC2 (not from the table cells). Give it the identifier "openVC2".

Comment: Hey Tim thanks for the help, appUsers is an array of objects that holds a reference to every user from a query. It is called in the class on VC1 and the results stored in it are from a query. Everything is good to go in VC1 with your new code advice except on the line "appUserResult = appUsers[indexPath.row]" I have the error: " cannot subscript a value of type '[PFUser]' "

Comment: Hey Tim so I figuered out some stuff not sure if its a help or a hindrance though. I have edited my code any idea what the problem is now?

Comment: Yes, you've got to set the user details in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, not in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in VC1

Comment: So when I move userToShow from cell to didSelect like so: 
          `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
           userToShow = appUsers[indexPath.row]
            }`      When i click the cell on VC1 to view the selected users details on VC2 it crashes and says "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" Its not saving the user info selected in the cell and has nothing to display on VC2. That would be my guess anyway, any ideas???

Comment: That's weird. Is your segue linked to the cells in storyboard, or is it called programmatically?

Comment: Sorry if I've picked you up wrong still v new to coding. But my segue was created on storyboard connecting the cell on VC1 to VC2 and then I use a func for the segue in my code as seen above. So I'm guessing storyboard is the answer....

Comment: Yes, that's what I was asking. I'm stumped right now, Grace. The fact that it "worked" before and showed the last row means that it is passing the information correctly. Maybe update the question once more and show the exact code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: It only shows the last row when I have the userToShow = appUsers[indexPath.row] in the cell like above so maybe thats where it needs to go but I need to do something like clear userToShow or something I really don't know??? I can update the code above for when I its moved to didSelectRow but that one crashes the app instead of at least showing the last cell? What do you reckon?

Comment: `didSelectRow` is the right place for it. That means "I did select this particular row". `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is run on EVERY row, which is why it always gives you the last answer. In other words, it reset `userToShow` for every row, and finished with the last row.

Comment: Do you still have the `print` line in `didSelectRow` after setting userToShow? Try to print `userToShow` right after setting it, see if it's nil.

Comment: ok so I updated my code to didSelectRow above. I added print and ya when I click on the cell it prints only the user in that cell to the logs and double checked with all the users displaying and its the same it works on the logs.

Comment: That's good news! We're narrowing it down. So it is set in `didSelectRow` but somehow it is `nil` by the next view. Did you delete the `userToShow` line in `cellForRow`?

Comment: Yup deleted `userToShow`I have also tried changing the userToShow and userToShowDetail called at the top of the VCs to different variations `var userToShow = PFUser?()` opens VC2 but with no info displaying. The same can be said for using no ? and when I use `var userToShow: PFUser?` it returns the error found nil so its not how they are being called because no matter the way I set them they all return nil.

Comment: FYI the error returns on VC2 on line `userName.text = userToShowDetail["name"] as? String`

Comment: Found it! `didSelect` is called too late! Move the line to `willSelectRowAtIndexPath`!

Comment: As in just change it to this ya? `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
           userToShow = appUsers[indexPath.row]
            print(userToShow)`                                                                        Doing that returns the error:  objective-C method 'tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:' provided by method 'tableView(_willSelectRowAtIndexPath:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'tableView(_:willSelectRowAtIndexP...

Comment: Thank you by the way for sticking with me and helping me out anyone else would have left long ago!!!

Comment: There's a slight error somewhere, and I'm still not happy with this answer. I swear I use `didSelectRow` all the time.

Comment: Check the updates I just made to the answer. Call the segue in the code and it should work.

Comment: Note that you should go back to `didSelectRow`

Comment: Ok so doing what you suggested using `var userToShowDetail: PFUser?` and I'm afraid it the same it just shows the VC with nothing updated ie. blank labels

Comment: Did you delete the old segue and create the new one?

Comment: ya and I did it the way you said from the VC1 to the other VC2 and named it  openVC2

Comment: Whoops! We have to change this line `if segue.identifier == "userProfileDetailsSegue"` to `if segue.identifier == "openVC2"`!

Comment: Ok so changed it and still the same, blank labels when it segues to VC2. Its still printing everything to the logs so I don't get it all!!!

Comment: I added print(userToShowDetail) on VC2 and it prints nil. so the info is not carrying between the segues coz the info prints before the segue.

Comment: Check the image I just added to the answer, make sure your segue looks the same. You drag from the yellow circle on top of the tableview (VC1) and drag to the body of VC2 (which is blue in my pic).

Comment: Send me the github link.

Comment: You put `let userToShow = self.appUsers[indexPath.row]` back in `prepareForSegue`. It needs to be in `didSelectRow`

Comment: Or is this the original version?

Comment: the latest version is in the branch latest-changes

Comment: prepareForSegue needs an `override`

Comment: And you used my variable `appUserResult` in `didSelectRow` instead of your version `userToShow`

Comment: `let userToSow` is 100 % in the right place, maybe I committed to github wrong I'm still figuring out github I never used it before last week. Is the branch latest-changes updated?

Comment: No I wasn't looking at the latest-changes

Comment: ya when you put in appUserResult I changed userToShow to appUserResult just to make sure no mistakes happened in translation. I had override in but it threw an error unless it was deleted.

Comment: Look at the version of `prepareForSegue` that you commented out. You're missing one of the arguments (sender: AnyObject?)

Comment: You bloody hero!!! thats it!!! will you edit your answer to put (sender: AnyObject?) in and I will mark it correct!!! Hero thanks so much for your detailed help!!!

Comment: Done! Ha, you should never trust my code, just type it in and let Xcode finish it! :)

Comment: Thanks again!!! I have actually been trying to solve that conundrum for about 2 weeks now!!! The app is for college due in  two weeks and I had given up on getting that function to work!!!

Comment: That's a major iOS function, so it's good to not give up on it. Look for some tableView tutorials to get a better hang of it.

Comment: Will do! I can't wait to be finished my time crunch and actually spend some time fixing it up in a lot of places at the mo its kinda just priority functions to get a grade and then I'll come back to it and make her pretty!!!